# How to refactor custom http client class?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a class for http client class in my project i need to add log and duration time.

this is class:

```
class RestClient {

public static function get($provider, $step, $url, $headers = [], $data = [])
{
    return self::request(
        Http::acceptJson()->withHeaders($headers),
        'get',
        $url,
        $provider,
        $step,
        $data
    );
 }

 private static function request($pendingRequest, $method, $url, $provider, $step, $data = [])
 {
    $startTime = microtime(true);
    $client = $pendingRequest->{$method}($url, $data);
    $durationTime = microtime(true) - $startTime;

    if ($client->clientError() || $client->serverError()) {
        HttpLog::addErrorLog(
            $provider, $step, $data, $client->toException()->getMessage(), $url, $durationTime
        );

        if ($client->status() == 401) {
            throw new InvalidTokenException();
        }

        if ($client->serverError()) {
            throw new ServerException();
        }

        throw new ProviderException('ProviderException');
     }

    HttpLog::addLog(
        $provider, $step, $client, $url, $durationTime
    );

    return $client->json();
 }
}
```

I call RestClient get method and other method in multi place my project.

example call :

```
return RestClient::get(
            $this->providerName(),
            'INQUIRY',
            {$this->configs['base_url'],
            ['Authorization' => "Bearer $token",]
        );
```

Do I need to refactor RestClient class?

Comment: If you throw an exception, will it still log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what exactly do you mean saying "refactor".
But if you are asking about a best way to extend the behaviour of existing service, I would say it is pattern Decorator. But it needs to get rid of static methods.
Also it would be better to register RestClient as a service in DI container (if you are using Lumen here is the manual https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.6/container)

The result code may look like:

```
interface RestClientInterface
{
    public function get(string $url, array $data): array;
    public function post(string $url, array $data): array;
}

class RestClient implements RestClientInterface
{
    private $provider;

    public function __construct(ProviderInterface $provider) {
        $this->provider = $provider;
    }

    public function get(string $url, array $data): array {
        // do actual GET request using provider and return response, no additional actions
    }
    public function post(string $url, array $data): array {
       // do actual POST request using provider and return response, no additional actions
    }
}

class LoggingClient implements RestClientInterface
{
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(RestClientInterface $decorated) {
       $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function get(string $url, array $data): array {
        $result = $this->decorated->get($url, $data);
        // here do additional actions, logging etc
        return $result;
    }

    public function post(string $url, array $data): array {
        $result = $this->decorated->get($url, $data);
        // here do additional actions, logging etc
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Then register the client implementation in the container and extend it with needed decorators:

```
$this->app->bind(RestClient::class, function ($app) {
    return new RestClient(new MyProvider());
});

$this->app->extend(RestClient::class, function ($decoratedClient, $app) {
    return new LoggingClient($decoratedClient);
});
```

Then get client instance in code like:

```
$client = $this->app->make(RestClient::class); // or App::make(RestClient::class)
```

With such approach you can wrap you service in many decorators, each of them will be responsible for doing one additional action. It gives more flexibility.

```
$service = new DecoratorOne(new DecoratorTwo(new BasicImplementation()));
```

Comment: is the best solutions. very good. edit my question and help to every one.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to reduce the number of arguments.
Consider to use chaining instead of static methods.

Example:

```
$restClient = new RestClient;
$restClient->provider($this->providerName());
$restClient->step("INQUIRY");
$restClient->url($this->configs['base_url']);
$restClient->headers(['Authorization' => "Bearer $token",]);
$restClient->get();
```

In my opinion, chaining will be more convenient to use

Comment: It would be better to inject parameters, which are always needed, as constructor parameters and save them in RestClient private fields. There is no actual need to pass provider each time when you need to make a request. Pass it to constructor once and reuse. But this also requires not to use static methods. In most cases static methods is a bad choice, because they make code dependencies rigid.